# Rigged Model - Editing Actions On Appended Rig Makes Rig Snap Back to Start Point

Tags: origin, actions

I have a construction worker model that I rigged and developed actions for (start walk, walk, end walk, idle, etc.).

I then appended the rigged model to the main file I was working in.

The rig and the actions came in fine. I then moved, scaled, and rotated the rig and applied all delta transforms.

The rig works just fine and the actions work correctly.

My only issue is that when I enter edit action mode, the rig snaps back to the last position I applied transforms at.

For example; I keyframe the movement of the rig as an action, add walk, add stop, add idle.

The animation works as expected. The model walks forward to a barrel object, stops and goes into idle after a second or two.

I want to adjust my idle action so that the model looks down at the barrel more, but whenever I enter Edit Actions, the rig snaps back to the place where I applied transforms. Then I don't have the barrel in front of the character model for reference.

I appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description, you are using both bones actions and object actions.
If so, try to avoid it: leave your rig in object mode at loc 000, rot 000, scale 111, and use a root bone (parent of the entire bone armature) to move, rotate and scale the rig as desired.

In this way you should be able to avoid this problem.

Comment: So for clarity; In Object mode, I moved the rigify rig (not the mesh) from its appended position (0,0,0) to its new start position and scaled it. I then set keyframes for the rig. The rig itself remains in place while moving and setting position keyframes for the rig position (in Object mode) and the actions work properly. It's only while editing a stashed action in the NLA that the rig moves back to its start position. When I stop editing the stashed action in the NLA, the object is back in its actual (animated) position.

Comment: I confirm that you should leave the rig in 000, 000, 111 in object mode, then in pose mode use the root bone to move, rotate and scale as needed, so that this transforms are part of the animation and don't get any change while editing a stashed action.

Comment: Okay... let me see if I get what you are saying. I rigged and animated the character at 0,0,0. After that, I can't just move the character to the start location in Object mode, set a keyframe, and apply the walk action? I have to move the rig in Pose mode? This seems very counter-intuitive... is the animation not linked to the rig so that if the rig moves, the animation stays with it? It seems like the opposite. I'm not sure I understand this.